# How do I visualize $\exp(z)$ as a complex mapping?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

How do I visualize $\exp(z)$ as a complex mapping? How can I ensure that it does not miss any value on the complex plane as it's value (is in the best condition of Picard's theorem). Can anyone help me?

Comment: [`ComplexPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `ComplexContourPlot` for visualising the real and imaginary axes on the complex `z` plane under the complex exponential mapping `Exp[z]`.

Define function for complex mapping:

`f[z_] := Exp[z]`

Then use `ComplexContourPlot` for visualising the contours:

Edit: `Contours` and `ContourLabels` added to `ComplexContourPlot` following [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) comment. This shows more clearly that the same lines are displayed in both contour plots.

```
{ComplexContourPlot[ReIm[z], {z, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}, PlotLabel -> z, 
   Contours -> {Range[-2, 2]}, ContourLabels -> All],
  ComplexContourPlot[ReIm[f[z]], {z, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}, 
   PlotLabel -> f[z], Contours -> {Range[-2, 2]}, 
   ContourLabels -> All]} // Grid[{#}, Frame -> True] &
```

The result:

[image]

Also you could look into the modulus and argument of `Exp[z]`. Perhaps this shows more clearly the mapping:

```
{ComplexContourPlot[AbsArg[z], {z, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}, PlotLabel -> z,
    Contours -> {Range[-3, 3]}, ContourLabels -> All],
  ComplexContourPlot[AbsArg[f[z]], {z, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}, 
   PlotLabel -> f[z], Contours -> {Range[-3, 3]}, 
   ContourLabels -> All]} // Grid[{#}, Frame -> True] &
```

[image]

Here you can see that circles in `z` plane (`Abs[z]`constant) are mapped into real lines `Exp[x+Iy] (*  Exp[x] is constant *)`, and that lines through the origin in the `z` plane (`Arg[z]`constant) are mapped into `Exp[x+Iy] (* y is constant*)` lines.

Comment: You might want to add something like `Contours -> {Range[-2, 2]}` to both plots so that the lines of both graphs correspond to each other.