# How do I draw a conformal mapping from the z-plane to the w-plane

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am total beginner in Mathematica. Don't know a thing. I need to draw some diagrams for showing the conformal nature of map $w=e^z$.

I need to draw some contours in $z$-plane; e.g., horizontal line, vertical line, 45 degree line and unit circle. Then I need to obtain the mapped curves in $w$-plane where $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x$ and $y$.

I have no idea how to do this? Please help me.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231371/how-do-i-visualize-expz-as-a-complex-mapping/231379#231379

Answer (score 7):

**Reply to the comment.**

Use `MeshShading` to fill the region.

```
expr1 = {x, y};
expr2 = With[{z = x + I*y}, E^z // ReIm // ComplexExpand];
ParametricPlot[#, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &, #4 - #3 &, Sqrt[#3^2 + #4^2] &}, 
    Mesh -> {{1}, {1}, {0}, {1}}, 
    MeshShading -> {{{{Red, None}, {None, None}}, {{Red, None}, {None,
          None}}}, {{{None, None}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
         None}, {None, None}}}}, 
    MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Red, Opacity[1]}, {Thick, Green, 
       Opacity[1]}, {Thick, Blue, Opacity[1]}, {Thick, Yellow, 
       Opacity[1]}}, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> 4, 
    BoundaryStyle -> None, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", Blue}, PlotPoints -> 80, 
    PlotStyle -> None] & /@ {expr1, expr2} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

**Simplify**

```
expr1 = {x, y};
expr2 = With[{z = x + I*y}, E^z // ReIm // ComplexExpand];
ParametricPlot[#, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &, #4 - #3 &, Sqrt[#3^2 + #4^2] &}, 
    Mesh -> {{1}, {1}, {0}, {1}}, 
    MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Red, Opacity[1]}, {Thick, Green, 
       Opacity[1]}, {Thick, Blue, Opacity[1]}, {Thick, Yellow, 
       Opacity[1]}}, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> 4, 
    BoundaryStyle -> None, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", Blue}, PlotPoints -> 80, 
    PlotStyle -> None] & /@ {expr1, expr2} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

**Original**

```
expr = With[{z = x + I*y}, E^z // ReIm // ComplexExpand]
xy = ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, #2 - #1 &, Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2] &}, 
   Mesh -> {{1}, {1}, {0}, {1}}, 
   MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Red, Opacity[1]}, {Thick, Green, 
      Opacity[1]}, {Thick, Blue, Opacity[1]}, {Thick, Yellow, 
      Opacity[1]}}, PlotPoints -> 50, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
   PlotStyle -> None];
uv = ParametricPlot[expr, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &, #4 - #3 &, Sqrt[#3^2 + #4^2] &}, 
   Mesh -> {{1}, {1}, {0}, {1}}, 
   MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Red, Opacity[1]}, {Thick, Green, 
      Opacity[1]}, {Thick, Blue, Opacity[1]}, {Thick, Yellow, 
      Opacity[1]}}, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> 8, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, FrameLabel -> {u, v}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", Blue}, PlotPoints -> 80, 
   PlotStyle -> None];
GraphicsRow[{xy, uv}]
```

Comment: if you want a filled circle e.g, what is the code for that?

Comment: @runner maybe more complexied. See the updated.